# Do I have to save() my NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I'm quite new to iOS development and have the following question:

I'm using CoreData and I add a Element like this:

```
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Foo", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Foo
```

After restarting my App, it's still there. The question is:

When I should use the `NSManagedObjectContext.save()` function?

Comment: Is there a save anywhere else in the code?

Comment: No there is no save elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call save when you want to persist your changes to the disk.

Your method inserts a new object into the managedObjectContext. But the managedObjectContext is really just a temporary place to put things. When you create an object in a context, that doesn't automatically persist those changes to the Persistent Store until you call save on it.

Comment: Okay, and when I read the results, do I have to make a load or something before? I read them with a NSFetchRequest

Comment: No, your `NSFetchRequest` is your "load".